# When I click on button to edit my value, the state don't update the input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I have a form that is wrapped from app.js who receive props from there to update my inputs and buttons on the file cadastro.js, but when I click on edit register my button change to edit from my function getDerivedStateFromProps my input with description doesn't change. It just updates after I click two times on the button edit.

But if I debug on the console in the function getDerivedStateFromProps show me at the right time. What is the problem with my code?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Cadastrar from "./components/Cadastrar";
import Tabela from "./components/Tabela";

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        update: '',
        idTamanhoEditar: ''
    }


    editarRegistro = (idRegistroEditarTabela) => {
        this.setState({idTamanhoEditar: idRegistroEditarTabela})
    }

    updateTabela = (atualizarTabela) => {
        this.setState({update: atualizarTabela})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Cadastrar atualizarTabela={this.updateTabela} editarFromParent={this.state.idTamanhoEditar}/>
                <Tabela editarRegistro={this.editarRegistro} updateFromParent={this.state.update} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default App;
```

**Cadastrar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Cadastrar.css';
import axios from "axios";

class Cadastrar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tamanho: {
                id: '',
                descricao: '',
            },
            error: '',
            sucess: '',
            tipoAcao: 'Cadastrar'
        };

        this.atualizaDados      = this.atualizaDados.bind(this);
        this.cadastrar          = this.cadastrar.bind(this);

    }

    atualizaDados(e) {
        let tamanho = this.state.tamanho;
        tamanho[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

        this.setState({tamanho: tamanho});

    }

    cadastrar(e) {

        const {tamanho} = this.state;
        if(tamanho.descricao !== '') {
            axios.post(`http://localhost/react-project/src/api/register.php`, { descricao: tamanho.descricao })
                .then(res => {
                    if(res.data === 'sucess') {
                        this.setState({tamanho:{id:'', descricao: ''}})
                        //Tabela.atualizarItensTabela();
                        this.setState({sucess: 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!', error: ''})
                        this.props.atualizarTabela(true);
                    }
                })
        } else {
            this.setState({error: 'Preencha o campo descrição!', sucess: ''})
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {


        if(props.editarFromParent !== state.tamanho.id  ) {
            console.log("Entrou");

            state.tamanho.id = props.editarFromParent;
            state.tipoAcao = 'Atualizar';
            state = Cadastrar.consultarTamanho(state.tamanho.id, state);

        }

        return null;
    }

    static consultarTamanho(idTamanho, state) {

        axios.post(`http://localhost/react-project/src/api/consult.php`, { id: idTamanho })
            .then(res => {
                if(res.data.descricao) {
                    state.tamanho.descricao = res.data.descricao;
                }
            })

        return state;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id='formulario-de-cadastro' className='container'>
                <div className='page-header'>
                    <h2 className='titulo-cadastrar-tamanho'>Cadastrar Tamanho</h2>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.cadastrar}>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value={this.state.tamanho.id} onChange={ this.atualizaDados } /><br/>
                    <div className='form-group'>
                        <label htmlFor='descricao'>Descrição</label>
                        <input type='text' className='form-control' name='descricao' id='descricao' onChange={ this.atualizaDados } value={this.state.tamanho.descricao} /><br/>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>{this.state.tipoAcao}</button>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-danger ml-1'>Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                {this.state.error && <p className='alert alert-warning'>{this.state.error}</p>}
                {this.state.sucess && <p className='alert alert-success'>{this.state.sucess}</p>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Cadastrar;
```

**Tabela.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import './Tabela.css';

class Tabela extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tamanhos: [],
            tamanho: {
                id: '',
                descricao: ''
            },
        }

        this.apagarTamanho = this.apagarTamanho.bind(this);
        this.atualizarItensTabela = this.atualizarItensTabela.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.atualizarItensTabela();
    }

    atualizarItensTabela() {
        let url = 'http://localhost/react-project/src/api/consultAll.php';

        fetch(url)
            .then((r) => r.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({tamanhos: json});
            });
    }

    apagarTamanho(e, idTamanho) {

        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post(`http://localhost/react-project/src/api/delete.php`, { id: idTamanho })
            .then(res => {
                if(res.data === 'sucess') {
                    this.atualizarItensTabela();
                }
            })
    }

    editarTamanho(e, idTamanho) {
        this.props.editarRegistro(idTamanho);

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container mt-5'>
                {this.props.updateFromParent && this.atualizarItensTabela()}
                <table id='tabela-tamanhos' className='table table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Código</th>
                            <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
                            <th scope="col">Ações</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.tamanhos.map(
                            tamanho=>
                                <tr key={tamanho.id} className='row-tamanho'>
                                    <th scope="row">{tamanho.id}</th>
                                    <td>{tamanho.descricao}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button className='btn btn-primary mr-1' onClick={(e)=>this.editarTamanho(e, tamanho.id)}>Editar</button>
                                        <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={(e)=>this.apagarTamanho(e, tamanho.id)}>Apagar</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Tabela;
```

Comment: you need to use dafaultValue instead of value

Comment: It doesn't work as well =(

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from `getDerivedStateFromProps` you have to return an object to update the state

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

Change thegetDerivedStateFromProps `` method with the below. Return an object rather mutating the state.

```
 state = Cadastrar.consultarTamanho(state.tamanho.id, state);
    if (props.editarFromParent !== state.tamanho.id) {
      console.log("Entrou");
      return {
        tamanho: {
          id: props.editarFromParent,
          descricao: '',
        },
        error: '',
        sucess: '',
        tipoAcao: 'Atualizar'
      }
    }
    return null;
```

And Call the side effect `state = Cadastrar.consultarTamanho(state.tamanho.id, state);` in `componentDidUpdate`.

> If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.

Comment: Here something that I notice, when I click for the first time, the input is empty, but if I click on it again, the input fills with my previous click.